# Row-wise dataframe creation using SQL-style INSERT for improved legibility

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I have some reference tables in a script in which some values are occasionally updated manually.

With the usual column-wise [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) definition, it can become troublesome to identify the correct index to change in larger tables: for example, finding the 15th value in each column to change.

Whilst I know these could be defined externally (e.g. a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv)), I was wondering whether they could be more easily defined directly in the script for maximum visibility to other users.

---

A short example using column-wise `data.frame` creation:

```
data.frame(id = 1:3, 
           start = as.Date(c("2018-01-01", "2018-03-02", "2018-05-14")), 
           end = c(as.Date("2018-06-30"), Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()))
```

And using row-wise data.frame creation which still requires explicit variable names in each `data.frame` (otherwise column names may not match for `rbind`):

```
rbind(
  data.frame(id = 1, start = as.Date("2018-01-01"), end = as.Date("2018-06-30")),
  data.frame(id = 2, start = as.Date("2018-03-02"), end = Sys.Date()),
  data.frame(id = 3, start = as.Date("2018-05-14"), end = Sys.Date())
)
```

How this may be achieved in [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) (clearest legibility in my opinion):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id int,
  start_date date,
  end_date date
);

INSERT INTO test
VALUES (1, '2018-01-01', '2018-06-30'),
       (2, '2018-03-02', SYSDATE),
       (3, '2018-05-14', SYSDATE);
```

---

I'd also be interested to hear if this is bad practice in general and whether just storing every reference table in a CSV is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) sqldf package** You can do this:

```
library(sqldf)

SYSDATE <- format(Sys.Date())
fn$sqldf("with test(id, start_date, end_date) as 
  (
     values
       (1, '2018-01-01', '2018-06-30'),
       (2, '2018-03-02', '$SYSDATE'),
       (3, '2018-05-14', '$SYSDATE')
  )
  select * from test")
```

**2) tibble package** Another possibility is:

```
library(tibble)

SYSDATE <- format(Sys.Date())
test <- tribble(
  ~id, ~start_date, ~end_date,
  1, '2018-01-01', '2018-06-30',
  2, '2018-03-02', SYSDATE,
  3, '2018-05-14', SYSDATE)
```

**3) Base R** Using only base R we can do:

```
Lines <- "
id start_date end_date  
1 2018-01-01 2018-06-30
2 2018-03-02 2019-01-03
3 2018-05-14 2019-01-03
"
read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Never used the `tribble` function before but that looks perfect. Thanks for all the suggestions!